# Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, blob, filereader

I've got a problem with a javascript Filereader which returns the error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Here's the javascript:

```
                    var blob = null;
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                    xhr.open("GET", "C:\\Users\\yw1kew\\Desktop\\LG_FRAME.plmx"); 
                    xhr.responseType = "blob";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
                    xhr.onload = function() 
                    {
                        blob = xhr.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
                    }
                    xhr.send();
                    var myReader = new FileReader();
                    myReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob) // THE CODE FAILS HERE
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: May be due to use of local file path  , try it on a webserver.Also you are reading it the wrong way see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215538/using-filereader-readasarraybuffer-on-changed-files-in-firefox)

Comment: This request is asynchronous, so the line `blob = xhr.response;` can very possibly be executed _after_ the line ` myReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);`. The error happens because `blob` still evaluates to `null` at that moment.
You could fix it by moving the FileReader operations in your `onload` function.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and after a few hours of searching the solutions online, I realised I might just be able to use fetch, which does indeed work !

```
fetch("./file.bin")
  .then((data) => {
    return data.arrayBuffer();
  })
  .then((array) => {
    console.log(buffer);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: the 6th line should be:  console.log(array); or change the parameter name from "array" to "buffer".

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use SharePoint as a platform and I needed to convert the binary code like this:

```
    binaryDecode = function (data) {
    var ret = '';
    if (data) {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.byteLength; i++) {
            ret = ret + String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
console.log(binaryDecode(arrayBuffer));
```