# How can I access JS arrays contained in a file after opening it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file-io

**UPDATE:**
I'm saving multidimensional arrays of the form:

```
var a = ["t1","a",["t2","a","b",["t3","a","b"],["t4","a","b","c",["t5","a","b"]],],["t6","a","b",["t7","a","b"]]];
```

in a file calling a standard save file function using JSON.stringify(a) -**without** the "var a = " and the ";" and later I open the file to a variable like this:

```
<a id="nof"><label for="fid">Open Data</label></a>
<input id="fid" type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em" onchange="ReadFile(this)">

function ReadFile(input) {
    var output;

    if (input.files.length === 0) {
        output = 'No file selected';
        window.setTimeout(ReadFile, 1000);
        return;
    }

    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
        var data = fr.result;
        var array = new Int8Array(data);
        output = JSON.stringify(array, null, '  ');

        console.log(array); // output //<------ 
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
```

I tried to adapt the code from this post: [Using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() on changed files in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215538/using-filereader-readasarraybuffer-on-changed-files-in-firefox) ) but I can't assign the data on a variable as a JS array. What I'm getting in console from "array" variable is:

```
Int8Array(117) [91, 34, 116, 49, 32, 118, 49, 57, 49, 49, 49, 53, 49, 56, 51, 51, 51, 34, 44, 34, 97, 34, 44, 91, 34, 116, 50, 34, 44, 34, 97, 34, 44, 34, 98, 34, 44, 91, 34, 116, 51, 34, 44, 34, 97, 34, 44, 34, 98, 34, 93, 44, 91, 34, 116, 52, 34, 44, 34, 97, 34, 44, 34, 98, 34, 44, 34, 99, 34, 44, 91, 34, 116, 53, 34, 44, 34, 97, 34, 44, 34, 98, 34, 93, 93, 93, 44, 91, 34, 116, 54, 34, 44, 34, 97, 34, 44, 34, 98, 34, …]
```

Obviously because the data are converted to int8.

From "output" variable I'm getting:

```
{"0": 91,"1": 34,"2": 116,"3": 49,"4": 32,"5": 118,"6": 49,"7": 57,"8": 49,"9": 49,"10": 49,"11": 53,"12": 49,"13": 56,"14": 49,"15": 51,"16": 52,"17": 48,"18": 34,"19": 44,"20": 34,"21": 97,"22": 34,"23": 44,"24": 91,"25": 34,"26": 116,"27": 50,"28": 34,"29": 44,"30": 34,"31": 97,"32": 34,"33": 44,"34": 34,"35": 98,"36": 34,"37": 44,"38": 91,"39": 34,"40": 116,"41": 51,"42": 34,"43": 44,"44": 34,"45": 97,"46": 34,"47": 44,"48": 34,"49": 98,"50": 34,"51": 93,"52": 44,"53": 91,"54": 34,"55": 116,"56": 52,"57": 34,"58": 44,"59": 34,"60": 97,"61": 34,"62": 44,"63": 34,"64": 98,"65": 34,"66": 44,"67": 34,"68": 99,"69": 34,"70": 44,"71": 91,"72": 34,"73": 116,"74": 53,"75": 34,"76": 44,"77": 34,"78": 97,"79": 34,"80": 44,"81": 34,"82": 98,"83": 34,"84": 93,"85": 93,"86": 93,"87": 44,"88": 91,"89": 34,"90": 116,"91": 54,"92": 34,"93": 44,"94": 34,"95": 97,"96": 34,"97": 44,"98": 34,"99": 98,"100": 34,"101": 44,"102": 91,"103": 34,"104": 116,"105": 55,"106": 34,"107": 44,"108": 34,"109": 97,"110": 34,"111": 44,"112": 34,"113": 98,"114": 34,"115": 93,"116": 93,"117": 93}
```

So, what is necessary to assign the file data as a JS array variable?

***I don't want to use a more complex format than the above example array (on the top of the page) that uses more characters, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Rather than storing the arrays in JavaScript source code form, you'd be better off storing them as JSON so you can parse them with `JSON.parse`. If you use JavaScript source code form, you need to fire up a full JavaScript parser, which can be a security hazard. (Though in this case, since you're doing it in response to the user specifying the file, it's not likely to be a significant one.) Moreover, it's awkward to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: *"I tried to adapt the code from this post but I can't make it work"* Show us that attempt, so we can help you understand why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: The example you've shown of the file you're saving isn't [JSON](https://json.org), and the question still doesn't have any attempt at reading the file with `FileReader`, which is the code I was [referring to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876719/how-can-i-access-js-arrays-contained-in-a-file-after-opening-it?noredirect=1#comment104020961_58876719).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder
I have changed the question and added a working code, but I'm not getting the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

*Codes below displayed in html div.
If you want to store in array, replace it.*

Try this:

```
function readFile(file) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = x=> resolve(fr.result);
fr.readAsText(file);
})}

async function read(input) {
  msg.innerText= await readFile(input.files[0]);
}

<input type="file" onchange="read(this)"/>
<h3>Content:</h3><pre id="msg"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! But code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, *why*, and *how* it works. This also doesn't access the arrays in the file, just the text. (You might also point out that this is *very* modern code, `async`/`await` is ES2018+.)

Comment: @Blaze
Thanks, but replacing the msg.innerText with a var isn't enough to load the array, it requires the following:   var a = await read(input.files[0]);  var n = JSON.parse(a);
Then your answer will be complete for the question I asked.